# How do you compile a console application with VS Code (Windows platform)?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code

The question is pretty straightforward. Using VS Code (not visual studio), I've been able to run it using the `dnx run` command but how am i supposed to ask for anyone to install it in order to run the application?

In other words, is it possible to generate an executable from VS code?

Update 1:

The selected answer is almost complete. I had to download the Microsoft Build Tools in order to use msbuild, and also had to create a .csproj file, which wasn't provided by the Yeoman generator i used to create the project.

Comment: You just compile to an .exe file and deploy it. Where does `dnx` come into this? Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx

Comment: i'm using vscode, no visual studio. I guess i can compile using the command line in that case

Comment: Wow I had no idea VSCode even existed up till now! Thank you for educating me :)

Comment: no problem mate hahaha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not as simple as it should be, but the way to do this is through the command palette (F1 key) and type `run task`, it should look like this:

[image: F1 Command Palette Run Task]

After you click this you will probably get an error in which you do not have a task runner created, you can either press the button or go back to the command palette and edit task runners.

What this will do is create a .vscode directory with a tasks.json file in it, you can either rummage through and uncomment the msbuild section or simply paste this as an override:

```
{   
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "msbuild",
    "args": [
        // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.       
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"  
    ],
    "taskSelector": "/t:",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.            
            "showOutput": "silent",
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings          
            // and infos in the output.
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }   
     ] 
 }
```

Once you've done that you can edit to your build specifications and either the command palette or CTRL+SHIFT+B will run the builder. Here is the link information for the Tasks: [Tasks in visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: I will try this one, but just to make it clear, it will generate a fully executable?

Comment: because all i managed to do thus far is to generate a *.cmd file that won't run unless i use 'dnx run' on a command prompt

Comment: @v1n1akabozo When configured with this you are running MSBUILD. Just as if you were compiling from the command line.

Comment: Just found this out by myself hahaha. Only issue is that it won't work because this tasks file is on another folder, in which there's nothing to build. How can i target the build to a upper folder?

Comment: managed to make it work by creating a csproj file for the project. Yeoman generator won't create one and that's why it wasn't working properly.