# Visual Studio creates an exe file that gets access denied, is this a file structure problem?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I have created lots of C# apps with Visual Studio before, but this week I ran into the strange situation that the created `.EXE` cannot be run, with error message: `Access is Denied`, actually because the laptop is Dutch: `Toegang geweigerd`.

[image: command line error message for VS made EXE]

[image: error dialog with Access Denied / Toegang geweigerd for an EXE made by VS]

Normally I would suspect that it is because of the virus scanner, especially because this is a new laptop. Also, it is managed by the security dept of my employer. Unfortunately, that dept does not really respond to my request for support on this. However, occasionally I do get system security warnings like below for DLL's produced by Visual Studio , that makes me believe that the virus scanner is not the problem:

[image: security warning with options for Load or Not Load a certain DLL]

When googling I found a [Microsoft advice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-folders-in-windows-219af563-1953-ab4a-f17e-b0182755214e) suggesting that the problem EXE might be encrypted. New theory:

*Visual Studio builds the EXE in a file format that is not entirely "correct" or without a checksum so that Windows cannot verify or find the checksum that matches the contents of the file.*

In order to simply test this, I looked for a small EXE in folder C:\Windows, and found hh.exe. I have no idea what this is good for, it opens a small window with a title bar like: html tester. In any case, this command can be started from the command line without error message.

Then, I opened hh.exe in Notepad++ and removed a number of bytes from the middle, and saved as hh_test.exe. Quite a butcher type of modification, but when calling this new exe from the command line, it gave the same error message!

For a more reproducible test, I created another invalid EXE by concatenating TWO exe's:

```
copy/b hh.exe+hh.exe hh2.exe
```

This new EXE is indeed exactly twice the original byte size. It causes the same error message:

[image: command line error message Access Denied (Toegang geweigerd) for a certain EXE]

These two tests support my theory that Visual Studio somehow produces EXE files that are not acceptable for Windows, and that this has nothing to do with the virus scanner. But I don't know much about the structure of the Windows EXE file. According to Wikipedia on Portable Executable, the EXE has some complex structure.

I already tried building a Release and a Debug version of the EXE, both have the same error.

My question now is:

*What settings do I need to check in Visual Studio to produce runnable EXE ?*

The versions for .NET and OS are not critical for me, as I want to do very simple tests in C#. The project settings for Target Framework, Target OS, Target OS Version, Supported OS Version are unclear for me. I just need anything that just runs :-)

Versions: Visual Studio Professional 2022, Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2.

Thanks for any help!

---

update:

I tried to create, build and run, a console type Hello World app with VS Code, and that ran OK. So no virus checker problem here.

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce that the EXE from VS Code can run. Neither the DLL using the Dotnet command. Something unclear must have changed.

But creating an app with VS Code works different, so I had to find some info, and found [this info on the dotnet command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874894/c-sharp-visual-studio-code-building-a-hello-world-executable). So I tried to run the EXE and the DLL using the dotnet command, and the same for the build from Visual Studio (not Code). What I found was:

- The VS app runs with command: dotnet x.DLL

I also ran: dotnet --info x.EXE, which showed a lot of warnings and info on installed frameworks, but does not really help.

This means that for now I can continu with doing some dev stuff in a standalone app by running the DLL using the DOTNET command. But I hope that some time the EXE problem can be fixed...

Comment: Very rarely, such issues may happen due to file system issues (although it is unlikely after your description). Anyway: Try checkdisk and reboot.